# Getting rid of image frames in swift/spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am working on an app that involves images colliding with one one another. Once they collide some code runs but the problem is the images backgrounds collide even though they are see through the square back ground is still there. How do I get rid of this invisible back ground or frame so that the only thing that collides is the image. Could you please give me an answer o this is refer me to a place that has the answer.

Comment: not really following

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your colliding images have SKPhysicsBodies that are rectangular in shape, based onthe size of your images? If it is essential that only the non-transparent part of the image can cause a colission, you might want to investigate creating the SKPhysicsBody using the images texture, using either `SKPhysicsBody(texture:size:)` or `SKPhysicsBody(texture:alphaThreshold:size:)`

Bear in mind that these are more expensive (in terms of processing power required) than simple rectangles.

So for an actual example:

```
let mySpriteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "mySprite")
let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: mySpriteTexture)
let myPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: mySpriteTexture, size: mySprite.size)

mySprite.physicsBody = myPhysicsBody
```

But this will require your image file `mySprite.png` to have been created with some transparency in it.

Comment: This will only work if your image background is actually transparent i.e. alpha - if it's just the same colour as the screen (e.g. black on a black background) then it will be considered part of the image.

Comment: Thanks for the response but Im not sure what I should put for texture or size and how I would find those values.

Comment: The images that you are using - these are SKSpriteNodes I assume? Are you creating them from .png files or similar?

Comment: These are SKSpriteNodes created from png files. (The backgrounds are transparent as well) –

Comment: Have added an example to my answer.